# Hot reloading breaks when encountering Typescript error

Tags: typescript, webpack, hot-reload

The dev server fails to compile once encoutering the ts error.

Even if  I fix the error and save the file, the hot reload still not works and I have to restart the devserver to make it work.

I have found the related issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8667) but there's no solution for now...

is there any solution?